# Analyze abstract class in php

Tags: php, class, abstract

i have become a bit confused about abstract class ! i have read more of the post written in stackoverflow and another website but i didn't understand ! so i took a look at my book again  but i didn't understand it either . so please analyze  the code below step by step  :

thanks in advance

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractClass
{
 abstract protected function getValue();
 public function printOut() {
 print $this->getValue();
 }
}
class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass
{
 protected function getValue() {
 return "ConcreteClass1";
 }
}
class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractClass
{
 protected function getValue() {
 return "ConcreteClass2";
 }
}
$class1 = new ConcreteClass1;
$class1->printOut();

$class2 = new ConcreteClass2;
$class2->printOut();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition

> 'An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract —it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed. An abstract method is a method that is
>   declared without an implementation'.

If defined an abstract class, you should extend that class with another.
In case of having abstract methods within the abstract class, you should write them in the child class in order to instantiate the child.

**Related to the code**, that is why when you instantiate the ConcreteClass, the getValue function is 'overwritten' to the pattern, while calling to the printOut method is from the father itself, because It is already written and not overwritten by the child. (See also that method was not abstract, that is why you can also use it from the father class)

Comment: thanks for your great explanation ! but just one thing !  Do we write " abstract protected function getValue(); " to say that this function isn't here (in parent class) . it belongs to extended class .?! so whenever we call "printOut" function from extended class , and the function includes " print $this->getValue(); " it should have searched for getValue function in AbstractClass but because we wrote " abstract protected function getValue(); " , it searches for it in extended class ! am i right ?!

Comment: When calling a class if the child does not have the class implemented, usually after goes to the father. If you apply that logic you will understand that as getValue method is overwritten (in this case IT HAS TO otherwise you could not use a class which has abstract methods not implemented) when calling the printOut of the father it is automatically returning the value of the child. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. Abstact class mean, when you can not make a instance of it. You can not do this:

```
$abstract = new AbstractClass();
```

Comment: thanks but sth makes me confused ! that is do we  write "  abstract protected function getValue(); " to say that this function isn't here (in parent class) . it belongs to extended class .?! so whenever we call "printOut" function from extended class , and the function includes "   print $this->getValue();  "  it should have searched  for getValue function  in AbstractClass  but because we wrote "  abstract protected function getValue(); " , it searches for it in extended class ! am i right ?!

Comment: If in child define 'getValue()' you everytime overwrite a parent method same name even it is abstract method. Declared abstract method only say developer, when he have to in child  define method with same name and parameters. Abstract class with abstract methods is almost same like 'interface'.